# How to resolve Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'version' of undefined?

Tags: jquery, magento2.3.1

Here I am using  below jquery include in register.phtml

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" /></script>
```

so that is why coming to that issue.

So I need to solve it.

Comment: Can you check website source, I think you have load multiple jquery in your project

Comment: Truly only one load that is above. and the issue is coming. when I use more modern version then Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined error comes   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" /></script>.